# Added a swtich in a row and getting tapped on both.

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I created a tableView in titanium and added 1 row in it and 1 switch in the row. The problem I'm facing is when I tapped on a switch row also get tapped. How can i stop this? Is there any way to stop. I have read a couple of links in which they are saying add switch in a view and then add that view in row but this isn't working. Below is the code.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <TableView width="100%" height="60%" top="5">
            <TableViewRow height="50" onClick="dont" width="100%" backgroundColor=" yellow">
                <View width= "100%" height="100%" onClick="doNothing">
                    <Switch value="On" top="5" right="5" onClick="doNot"></Switch>
                </View>
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

When I tapped on a switch both function get called...
Titanium version: 3.4.1 GA

Answer (score 0):

This how you should do it :
Add onClick listener on the tableView and onChange Listener on the switch:

```
<Alloy>
   <Window class="container">
     <TableView width="100%" height="60%" top="5" onClick="dont">
        <TableViewRow height="50"  width="100%" backgroundColor=" yellow">
            <View width= "100%" height="100%">
                <Switch value="On" top="5" right="5" onChange="doSwitchChange"></Switch>
            </View>
        </TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

and in controller.js

```
function dont(e) {
    if (e.source == e.row.children[0])
        Ti.API.debug('the View');
    else
        Ti.API.debug('the Switch');
}

function doSwitchChange(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.value);
}
```